# How to apply Graph API v2.3 base on Facebook SDK v3.23.2?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Our product using Facebook SDK v3.23.2.
This Facebook SDK v3.23.2 include Graph API v2.2 version.

I have receive alert mail from facebook 3 days ago as like below.

> Your Product currently has access to Graph API v2.2 which will reach the end of its 2-year lifetime on 27 March, 2017. To ensure a smooth transition, please migrate all calls to Graph API v2.3 or higher.

To apply Graph API v2.3, we have to update from Facebook SDK v3.23.2 to Facebook SDK v4.XX.
Because Facebook SDK v3.XX doesn't support Graph API v2.3.

As you know, Facebook SDK v3.XX and v4.XX are very different.
Ex) class name, class structure, ....

So, to update Facebook SDK v4.XX on our product, we have to change so many source code.
Furthermore old verion product which is using Facebook SDK v3.23.2 had already released to market in case of Mobile(Android/iOS).
And we have some internal issues to update Facebook SDK v4.XX.

- Can I know how to apply Graph API v2.3 base on Facebook SDK v3.23.2?
- What if we have not applied Graph API v2.3 until March 27, 2017? Will Graph API v2.2 be no longer available?
- We hope to keep using Graph API v2.2

  Thanks!

Comment: No, you can not keep using v2.2 - that will be shut off. All API calls against lower API versions, or calls that do not specify the API version at all, will automatically go against the then lowest API version available.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you mean if we call Graph API 2.2 after blocking this version, response will be come as valid? or response will be come as error?

Comment: You should still get a response - but from API v2.3. So if your API requests use anything that was removed in v2.3, you will likely still get errors.